# Microsoft Sharepoint List Location Column - Geocoding Issues & Work Around

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, geocoding, sharepoint-list

I am building a solution to take programmatically analyze Locations from Microsoft Lists Sharepoint.  You can set a column of type "Location" to produce "Coordinates", HOWEVER, it appears to only do this for locations with a name.  If you plug in a residential address, it does not geocode the address which is a problem. It appears it may be possible to programmatically address this - does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you...

Comment: The Location column only implements geocode the address which already marked in the Bing map.